# Java CompletableFuture exception handling or propagating

Tags: java, exception, completable-future

I want to handle only exception of some type and rethrow it, if it is an exception of another type:

```
future.exceptionally
(
   (error) ->
   {
      bool wouldBeHandled = ...;
      if (wouldBeHandled)
      {
         Handle();
      }
      else
      {
         throw error; //Want to do this, but can't
         throw new RuntimeException(error); //I don't want to wrap 
      }
   }
);
```